# How to reuse jquery-ui-autocomplete cached results when appending search term?

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following JS method to bind the jQuery UI autocomplete widget to a search text box.  Everything works fine, including caching, except that I make unnecessary server calls when appending my search term because I don't reuse the just-retrieved results.

For example, searching for "ab" fetches some results from the server.  Typing "c" after "ab" in the search box fetches "abc" results from the server, instead of reusing the cached "ab" results and omitting ones that don't match "abc".

I went down the path of manually looking up the "ab" search results, filtering them using a regex to select the "abc" subset, but this totally seems like I'm reinventing the wheel.  What is the proper, canonical way to tell the widget to use the "ab" results, but filter them for the "abc" term and redisplay the shortened dropdown?

```
function bindSearchForm() {
    "use strict";
    var cache = new Object();

    $('#search_text_field').autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var term = request.term;
            if (term in cache) {
                response(cache[term]);
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/get_search_data',
                    data: {q: term},
                    success: function (data) {
                        cache[term] = data;
                        response(data);
                    }
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting problem, but how much is this actually saving you? It seems like it might be more trouble than its worth...

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: this could save quite a bit for a large dataset; e.g. appending "c" and then "d" to the initial "ab" search term currently results in three server calls vs. potentially just the single initial call.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't know that there is a canonical way to do this. You're going to have to iterate over each item in the cache and retrieved the cached result that's a prefix of what you've searched for. Then you'll need to filter the results of *that* search by the current search term.

Comment: Exactly the same problem over here. What is the point in caching everything beginning 'ca' for example, if then when I add a letter instead of going to the cache it just goes back to the server and caches a new search term. Very weird behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my "brute-force, reinventing the wheel" method, which is, for now, looking like the right solution.

```
function bindSearchForm() {
    "use strict";
    var cache = new Object();
    var terms = new Array();

    function cacheNewTerm(newTerm, results) {
        // maintain a 10-term cache
        if (terms.push(newTerm) > 10) {
            delete cache[terms.shift()];
        }
        cache[newTerm] = results;
    };

    $('#search_text_field').autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var term = request.term.toLowerCase();
            if (term in cache) {
                response(cache[term]);
                return;
            } else if (terms.length) {
                var lastTerm = terms[terms.length - 1];
                if (term.substring(0, lastTerm.length) === lastTerm) {
                    var results = new Array();
                    for (var i = 0; i < cache[lastTerm].length; i++) {
                        if (cache[lastTerm][i].label.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) !== -1) {
                            results.push(cache[lastTerm][i]);
                        }
                    }
                    response(results);
                    return;
                }
            }
            $.ajax({type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/get_search_data',
                    data: {q: term},
                    success: function (data) {
                        cacheNewTerm(term, data);
                        response(data);
                        return;
                    }
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: FYI I tried to work your solution into my multiple autocomplete selector but I've spend nearly a day trying to get it to work now, so just going to leave the caching as it was and have more trips to the server :(

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants a version that supports multiple entries in the text box then please see below:

```
$(function () {
function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}

var cache = new Object();
var terms = new Array();

function cacheNewTerm(newTerm, results) {
    // keep cache of 10 terms
    if (terms.push(newTerm) > 10) {
        delete cache[terms.shift()];
    }
    cache[newTerm] = results;
}

$("#searchTextField")
    .on("keydown",
        function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
    .autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var term = extractLast(request.term.toLowerCase());
            if (term in cache) {
                response(cache[term]);
                return;
            } else if (terms.length) {
                var lastTerm = terms[terms.length - 1];
                console.log('LAst Term: ' + lastTerm);
                if (term.substring(0, lastTerm.length) === lastTerm) {
                    var results = new Array();
                    for (var i = 0; i < cache[lastTerm].length; i++) {
                        console.log('Total cache[lastTerm[.length] = ' +
                            cache[lastTerm].length +
                            '....' +
                            i +
                            '-' +
                            lastTerm[i]);
                        console.log('Label-' + cache[lastTerm][i]);
                        var cachedItem = cache[lastTerm][i];
                        if (cachedItem != null) {
                            if (cachedItem.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) !== -1) {
                                results.push(cache[lastTerm][i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    response(results);
                    return;
                }
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetSearchData", "Home")',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
                data: {
                    term: extractLast(request.term)
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    cacheNewTerm(term, data);
                    response($.map(data,
                        function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item
                            };
                        }));
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        },
        search: function () {
            var term = extractLast(this.value);
            if (term.length < 2) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        focus: function () {
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            terms.pop();
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            return false;
        }
    });
```